# ¿Como cambiar el tipo de fuente(letra) de un gridview en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview, studio, fuentes

Hola tego una app con un gridview, me costo pero consegui que me metiera los datos de un  String array[][] bidimensional, funciona bien, pero no soy capaz de cambiar el tipo de fuente con que aparece el texto.
He buscado mucho por internet, y no he encontrado nada, he buscado en los atributos del grid y tampoco , 
he probado a ver si el adapter ,no me deja ,pero tampoco y el ArrayList.
Soy novato en programación en android studio.

No me importa si se hace por codigo o en el archivo de configuración del Layaout el archivo .xml

Pero estoy arto de buscar y no lo soluciono, ya no se que hacer( he perdido mucho tiempo).

Es esencial cambiar el tipo de fuente, esta fuente ya la que tengo instalada en android studio (y me funciona en textView) es un tipo de fuente con simbolos y debe ser esa por fuerza.
Se que para texview le pongo la ruta y lo configuro con setTypeface le doy la ruta de la fuente
Pero no consigo cambiar el tipo de letra del gridview.
¿como se hace? no me importa como se haga, ya que es el tipo de letra que tendra siempre desde el principio.

Muchas gracias.
Saludos.

P.D.: "IMPORTANTE,no me importa usar otra forma en vez de gridview, solo necesito que se muestren los datos en forma de tabla y controlar las casillas, pero no necesito que se genere ningun evento al clicar en ellas, por ello en ultima instancia podria cambiar a otra opción de tabla, aunque esta me costo mucho que funcionase."

Comment: Agrega lo que has tratado por favor, saludos.

Comment: Ya lo he dicho en mi mensaje "he buscado en los atributos del grid y tampoco , he probado a ver si el adapter ,no me deja ,pero tampoco y el ArrayList."